# I get none when using get_attribute in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need to click some rows in a table,
the table is like this:
[image: table rows]

the trs with bgcolor is those I've already reviewed.
I need to skip them.
I can't see the picture I uploaded, so I type some to acknowledge it.

```
<tr id ="1">...</tr>
<tr id ="2" bgcolor='B3D9D9'>...</tr>
<tr id ="3" bgcolor='B3D9D9'>...</tr>
<tr id ="4" >...</tr>
......
```

and the difference between tr1 and tr2, is the "bgcolor='B3D9D9'"，
and when I use web element inspector the check the css:
below content is correspondingly more here in CSS style:

```
tr[Attributes Style] {
background-color: rgb(179, 217, 217);
```

}

here is my code:

```
trs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/ html / body / table / tbody / tr / td / div / div[3] / table / tbody / tr')
total = len(trs)
print(total)  # I got '21' here 
order = 1
selected = 0
for number in range(1,total):
     current_tr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/ html / body / table / tbody / tr / td / div / div[3] / table / tbody / tr[%d]' % order)
     print(type(current_tr)) # class: webelement
     bgc = current_tr.get_attribute("bgcolor") 
     # print(bgc)  #None
     bgc2 = current_tr.get_attribute("background-color")
     # print(bgc2)  #None

     if current_tr.get_attribute("bgcolor") is not None: # == "#B3D9D9" 
        or current_tr.get_attribute("background-color") == "rgb(179, 217, 217)":
        print('pass')  #this is never been processed. so the if condition is never true. because it is None
        time.sleep(1)
        order = order + 1 
     else:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('// *[ @ id = "%d"] / td[6] / a' % order).click() # current status is every row is clicked.
        selected = selected + 1
        time.sleep(3)
```

don't mind the format, I garantee the format is ok. And I finally get every tr clicked. what I want is to skip the trs with bgcolor property.
I haven't get a "pass", that means get.attribute('bgcolor) is a none. But when I follow below Prophet's advice to add additional 'if', I still can not get pass. Which means is trully a None.  and i've done print debugging, yes ,it's now.
so the expression: get_attribute("bgcolor") =="#B3D9D9" is not correct?
Why?? it's so obvious.please kindly spot my fault...

Comment: "that means get.attribute('bgcolor) is a none" - why do you assume it's None? You need to post more of your code. Perhaps current_tr is not getting changed so you're always checking the same element. We cannot tell since you've posted too little code. Preferably, post a [mre].

Comment: it's changing. Because I have 'else' to handle click actions. When I iterate the trs, click action is ongoing. Only problem is what I said, I can not skip the trs with bgcolor.

Comment: You haven't shown where `current_tr` is getting set to any value much less changed.

Comment: Ok, I've attached what you want, I hope you can really help me.

Comment: `current_tr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/ html / body / table / tbody / tr / td / div / div[3] / table / tbody / tr[%d]' % order)` is set within your `for number in range(1,total):` loop. But `order` does not change within your loop so you're checking the same element each time through the loop.

Comment: Just like I said in my earlier comment.

Comment: Hello Justin, thanks very much, yes, that's the problem.  people tend to mistake where they ignore.  I have modified the for loop start-index: 'number' from 1 to 2. then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `current_tr` does not change within the loop! Your XPATH (`' ... table / tbody / tr[%d]' % order`) uses the variable `order` whose value never changes from the initial value (1) so you're checking the same Web Element every time. Perhaps you meant to use the variable `number` instead of `order` for your XPATH.

Your code:

```py
trs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/ html / body / table / tbody / tr / td / div / div[3] / table / tbody / tr')
total = len(trs)
print(total)  # I got '21' here 
order = 1
selected = 0
for number in range(1,total):
     current_tr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/ html / body / table / tbody / tr / td / div / div[3] / table / tbody / tr[%d]' % order)
     # irrelevant code snipped
```

Comment: Justin, you got it!

Comment: Good catch, Justin!

Answer (score 0):

This occurs since there are elements in the table without `bgcolor`  attribute.
So, when you trying to `current_tr.get_attribute('bgcolor')` on them it returns `NoneType` object.
Try this:

```
if current_tr.get_attribute('bgcolor') is not None:
    if current_tr.get_attribute('bgcolor') == '#B3D9D9' or current_tr.get_attribute('background-color') == 'rgb(179, 217, 217)':
        print('pass')
```

Comment: Hello, Prophet， thanks for your answer, I've tried your answer, but no effect.
I have attached more code to elaborate my case:
by the way , can you check the pictures. just for my inference, because even you can see the picture, it would be ok, because I've writen it down also.

Comment: Hello Prophet, I've checked your another answer for similiar question. get_attribute returns None. In my case, it's obviously attribute of the trs. And I've get the webelements.<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>  I was wondering why is None?

Comment: Probably the problem is in your code that is before the code you presented in the question. If `current_tr` is a `tr` web element as supposed applying `.get_attribute('bgcolor')` on it will return a string - the value of that attribute or None in case there is no such attribute for that element. `.get_attribute()` will never return a web element AFAIK

Comment: Yes, the proplem is returning None right now. of course it will never return a web element. My question is simple: why is returning None? the "bgcolor" attribute is obviously there.

Comment: instead of `.get_attribute('bgcolor')` try `.value_of_css_property('background-color')`. If still not working try `value_of_css_property("color")` or `value_of_css_property("style")`. Please let me know if that helped

Comment: tks, .get_attribute('bgcolor') is ok. thanks for your advice.